# Show more jquery to work with two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found following solution for "show more" functionality that, which works great. I need to enhance this to have two divs to expand/hide simultaneously.

[How to create a "show more" button and specify how many lines of text can be initially shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307666/how-to-create-a-show-more-button-and-specify-how-many-lines-of-text-can-be-ini/12308064#12308064)

Below is my updated code that does not work for some reason.

```
$(".show-more span").click( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.contentNav");
    var $contentDesc = $this.parent().prev("div.contentDesc");

    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();

    if(linkText === "(SHOW LESS)"){
        linkText = "more...";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 200);
        $contentDesc.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 200);

    } else {
        linkText = "(Show less)";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 200);
        $contentDesc.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 200);
    }
    $this.text(linkText);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: if the other div have the same class name, change var $this = $(this); to $('.show-more span'); this will show/hide all instead of this context

Comment: @Syahrul, thank you for your input; I replaced "var $this = $(this);" with "var $this = $('.show-more span');" but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var $contentDesc = $this.prev("div.contentDesc");` change it to `var $contentDesc = $content.prev("div.contentDesc");`

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show-more span").click( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.contentNav");
    var $contentDesc = $content.prev("div.contentDesc");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();

    if(linkText === "(SHOW LESS)") {
        linkText = "more...";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 200);
        $contentDesc.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 200);

    } else {
        linkText = "(Show less)";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 200);
        $contentDesc.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 200);
    }
    $this.text(linkText);
});
  });
```

```css
.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}
.showContent{
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="contentDesc hideContent"> 
  <p>Description</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor repudiandae non sit incidunt totam, error optio animi possimus saepe quidem voluptate molestias neque excepturi hic. Omnis, pariatur, aliquid. Facere, alias!</p>
</div>
<div class="contentNav hideContent"> 
 <p>Navigation content</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor repudiandae non sit incidunt totam, error optio animi possimus saepe quidem voluptate molestias neque excepturi hic. Omnis, pariatur, aliquid. Facere, alias!</p>
</div>
<div class="show-more" style="text-align: center; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><span>more...</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is not working because it cant find the second div, So check your code. To fix it put , `var $contentDesc = $this.parent().prev("div.content").prev();.`

Comment: @Blaze I just edit the post, the solution owner is Hashy ;-)

Comment: @Hashy - I tried your suggestion but that did not work. Here is the HTML I'm using. [code] <div class="contentDesc hideContent"> Description..... </div> <div class="contentNav hideContent"> Navigation content </div> <div class="show-more" style="text-align: center; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;"><span>more...</span> </div> [code]

Comment: @Blaze k, then as per your code you can put $contentDesc = $content.prev(); that will work too