# Display "Read More" Button based on number of lines in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a video page with video description.
Now I want to show description with 2 lines by default and below the description will be a 'Read More' button.

But if the description is less than or equal to 2 lines, I don't want to show the 'Read More' button. 'Read More' button will be shown only when description will be more than 2 lines.

I need this to be done completely with JS or jQuery.

Here is what I have tried so far with no luck.

```
<div class="video-description" style="line-height:1.2em;max-height:4.8em;">              
<p>
 Description Line 1
 Description Line 2
 Description Line 3
</p>        
</div>
<div class="read-more-button">Read More</div>

if ($('.video-description').css('height') <= '67px' {
   $('.read-more-button').hide();
} else {
   $('.read-more-button').show();
}
```

Comment: Please add your html etc. You should not be depending on pixel size etc.

Comment: And if you do want to use pixel size, use the .height() method as it gives a number without units as a return, which you can then use a greater-than-or-equal operator on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count text lines inside an DOM element? Can I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783899/how-can-i-count-text-lines-inside-an-dom-element-can-i)

Comment: the problem is more complicated as line-height returns "normal" when not set to pixel value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a "show more" button and specify how many lines of text can be initially shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307666/how-to-create-a-show-more-button-and-specify-how-many-lines-of-text-can-be-ini)

Comment: Added the html.

Comment: @Akrion But you can't quickly get pixels in em. The only way would be to create fake divs to check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally there is no simple way to detect how many lines of text are in `div`... the only reliable way would be to create invisible (with `visibility:hidden`) divs with 1 and 2 lines and that way to get height of line in div of given class. The problem with `em` is that there is no other way to get the height of the element in `em` as well.

As you are new, I will simply address your problem and why your example does not work... First of all, the way of getting element height is wrong... if there would be no `height` style set, it would return nothing, if style would be set, it would return value with units as a string and then You can't compare it as numbers. Second thing is that you are missing ending bracket (`)`) in your if condition, so you basically got syntax error.

You should use `height()` instead and a number in pixels to compare, for example:

```
if($('.video-description').height() <= 67){
   $('.read-more-button').hide();
} else {
   $('.read-more-button').show();
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you so much for taking time to explain.